# AWS CDK (Typescript) error in RDS Instance Creation: "Error: There are no 'Isolated' subnet groups in this VPC."

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cdk

In AWS CDK, I created a private subnet (without adding `mapPublicIpOnLaunch`) and I get this error when creating my RDS instance.

Here is my code of the steps I take to get everything prepared:

- I grab my VPC from my account
- Create a new private subnet
- Finally, use that private subnet for my private RDS DB.

> ```
> // Import VPC to be used.
> let mainVPC = ec2.Vpc.fromVpcAttributes(this, "test", {
>   vpcId: props.vpcId,
>   availabilityZones: ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1c"],
> });
>
> // Private subnet 1a
> const privateSubnet1A = new ec2.CfnSubnet(this, 'privateSub1A', {
>   availabilityZone: props.availabilityZones[0],
>   cidrBlock: props.cidr + '.2.0/24',
>   vpcId: props.vpcId,
>   tags: [{
>     key: 'Name',
>     value: props.availabilityZones[0] + '.' + "sandbox" + "." + "foo" + "." + 'bar'
>   }]
> });
>
> // Creates postgreSQL RDS instance:
> const foobarDBInstance = new rds.DatabaseInstance(this, "foo_bar", {
>   vpc: mainVPC,
>   vpcSubnets: {
>     availabilityZones: props.availabilityZones,
>     subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED,
>   },
>   engine: rds.DatabaseInstanceEngine.postgres({
>     version: rds.PostgresEngineVersion.VER_13_4,
>   }),
>   instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(
>     ec2.InstanceClass.BURSTABLE3,
>     ec2.InstanceSize.SMALL,
>   ),
>   credentials: rds.Credentials.fromGeneratedSecret('foo'),
>   securityGroups: [dbSG],
>   multiAz: false,
>   allocatedStorage: 100,
>   maxAllocatedStorage: 1000,
>   allowMajorVersionUpgrade: false,
>   autoMinorVersionUpgrade: true,
>   backupRetention: cdk.Duration.days(0),
>   deleteAutomatedBackups: true,
>   removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
>   deletionProtection: false,
>   databaseName: "foo bar",
>   publiclyAccessible: false,
> });
> ```

The error i receive is in the title of my question:
`Error: There are no 'Isolated' subnet groups in this VPC.`

So my question is, why is this happening? Is there a proper way of fixing this error? I would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Do you have a Subnet Group associated with those subnets in which the DB is being launched? If so you can specify the parameter 'subnetGroup' on rds.DatabaseInstance constructor

Comment: I do not. I believe it would be best for me to do so. Before I would create the subnets manually and then it would register in `subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED`.

Comment: The error in the title mentions Isolated subnets, while the body mentions Public subnets. Which is it?

Comment: @gshpychka apologies, you are correct. Updated question.

Comment: So just an update: I tried creating a class of `rds.SubnetGroup` on the side, and I am having such a hard time adding my subnets by referencing the private subnet. Trying to see how I can do this.

Comment: @Roma there's still a mismatch - is it Private or Isolated?

Comment: @gshpychka Ah man! Sorry for the confusion. It is `Isolated`.

Comment: How can a person notify that the subnets that I created are Isolated or Private for that matter?